# Kotlin: Unable to find the element in the Arraylist<String>

Tags: kotlin

My problem is bifurcated into:
Is this the correct syntax of entering the elements in the Arraylist? Is there any other alternative?
 Unable to find the element from the given code.

```
var arylst= arrayListOf<String>()
println("enter the elements of arraylist")

for(index in 0..arylst.size-1) {
arylst[index] = readLine()!!
if (arylst.contains("Ritika"))
println("element found")
else  
println("not found")
```

Comment: You are missing a closing brace `}` so your code won't compile. What exactly are you trying to do? Also, your loop won't do anything since you're iterating over the elements of an empty list (which is exactly 0 loop iterations).

Comment: Is there any reason why the [tag:kotlin-android-extensions] tag was added? I don't see any usage of Kotlin's Android Extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enter elements into an `ArrayList` from user input, you need to do something like

```
val arrayList = arrayListOf<String>()
println("Enter elements of array list")

while (true) {  // see bellow
    arrayList.add(readLine()!!)
    if (condition()) { // choose what this does
        break
    }
}

println(arrayList) // see what it looks like
```

Now what that `condition()` is is up to you. It could be a fixed number of enteries, or stop when an entry meets some condition.

---

For example, keep adding enteries until enter is pressed with no entry

```
val arrayList = arrayListOf<String>()
println("Enter elements of array list (or nothing to stop entering)")

while (true) {
    val entry = readLine()!!
    if (entry.length == 0) {
        break
    } else {
        arrayList.add(entry)
    }
}

println(arrayList)
```